# SQL WHERE statement not working

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I have written the following code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO donate (amount, reward) VALUES ('$amount', '$reward') WHERE id = ('$id')";
```

but I get this error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE id = ('19')' at line 1

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Either you want to update an existing row, or you want to insert a new one. `where` only has meaning when updating, not when inserting.

Comment: Do you mean to insert into table, if id = 19 ?

Comment: This isn't proper SQL syntax. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do INSERT with WHERE clause. If you need WHERE conditions, you needed to do `UPDATE`.

You can do with:

```
$sql="UPDATE donate SET amount='$amount', reward='$reward' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Comment: Your first two sentences are wrong, but the rest of the answer is correct.  (I didn't downvote the answer.)

Comment: To add to this, when updating multiple ids `"UPDATE donate SET amount='$amount', reward='$reward' WHERE id IN ([comma separated list of IDs])"`.

@Jenz I also do not have an idea why someone would downvote this answer.

Comment: @Takuya..Why comma separated id's.I can't see any comma separated values in the question.

Comment: @Jenz, I'm just adding to/expanding your answer. Updating rows with multiple matching IDs is a common pattern after all.

Comment: @Jenz may I ask why you included the brackets in your WHERE clause? Is it because the OP has it in the question, or specific to a particular type of SQL? I ask because it seems redundant to me.

Comment: @Takuya..If it is a comma separated value then it is better to use `where id in ($id)`. As if now, I don't think OP has CSV in that field as the query displays only 19 as value.

Comment: @Jenz, that's what I said/did? `$id='1,2,3'; $sql="... WHERE id IN ($id)"`. I'm not looking for an argument, I was just expanding your answer, regardless of what the OP wanted. It may be of use to the OP later, or may be of use to someone who comes across this post.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT`

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` syntax cannot have WHERE clause. The only time you will find INSERT has WHERE clause is when you are using `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement.

You can try

```
$sql="UPDATE donate SET amount='" . $amount. "', reward='" .$reward. "' WHERE id='" .$id. "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are insert record at time this record it is not available in your database table so you are not use with where.

Second you are use where cause only on existing database record like UPDATE or DELETE record.....

I hope for help you